# Are there any events before the screen got locked in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, screen-lock

As the title specifies, I want to know if any events will happen before the screen gets locked in Windows Phone 7, so that before the screen got locked I can use some combined conditions to determine setting the `IdleDetectionMode` to `Disabled` or not.

Or can we get the system screen locking time?

Comment: Before, not that I know of, there is obviously the 'Deactivated' event, have you tried using that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: @Layoric Thanks, Layoric. But actually the Deactivated wouldn't happand before the screen got locked.

Comment: correct, not exactly sure of your requirements, so I thought I'd suggest it. I don't believe there is such an event.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try using [Obscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)(Occurs when the shell chrome is covering the frame) and [Unobscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.unobscured%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)(Occurs when the shell chrome is no longer covering the frame) events for PhoneApplicationFrame.

You can always get the instance of PhoneApplicationFrame using (PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual, but be careful and do not create memory leaks.